# Printing by prototype not working in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a constructor function. Then I am trying to use its prototype and printing "Peter". But it is showing an error.

```js
function main(){

   var func1 = function(){
 this.name = "Peter";
 this.age = 27; 
 this.class = "10";
   }

   func1.prototype.printName = function(){
 console.log(this.name);
   }

   return func1; 
}

var a = main();

a.printName();
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/jYMbQWbcfZ6Q243Hu1Cf?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the constructor function `func1` to `a`, not an *instance* of `func1`. Only instances of `func1` have a `printName` method. At some point you need to call `new func1()` or `new a()`. E.g. you could do `return new func1();` instead of `return func1;`.

Have a look at the following, simplified example.

```js
var func1 = function() {
  this.name = "Peter";
  this.age = 27;
  this.class = "10";
}

func1.prototype.printName = function() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

var a = new func1();

a.printName();
```

I recommend to read [eloquentjavascript.net - The Secret Life of Objects](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html).